# Read number of significant bits of .png?

Tags: python, png

I have a set of 16bit pngs-files, recorded with LabVIEW. For some reason I need to bitshift them to use them. And for this, I need the number of significant bits. How can I read those using Python? In Matlab, there is a method called *imfinfo* which returns the significant bits.

Comment: You can get the number of significant bits of an `int` in Python3 with the `.bit_length` method.

Comment: A 16-bit PNG is assumed to have 16 significant bits per color component, but PNG also has an optional "sBIT" chunk which, if present, conveys the number of significant bits of each component.  Combine that information with the value from the .bit_length method suggested by @PM2Ring to find out how much you need to bitshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Glen Randers-Pehrson, I just read the sBIT chunk:

```
import struct
import binascii

def __header(bytes):
    return struct.unpack('>NNccccc', bytes)

def __getSBit(bytes):
    bytes = bytes[8:]

    sBit = 0

    while bytes:
        length = struct.unpack('>I', bytes[:4])[0]
        bytes = bytes[4:]

        chunk_type = bytes[:4]

        bytes = bytes[4:]

        chunk_data = bytes[:length]
        bytes = bytes[length:]

        if chunk_type == "sBIT":
            sBit = int(chunk_data.encode("hex"), 16)
            break

        bytes = bytes[4:]

    return sBit

def getSigniticantBits(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        bytes = f.read()

    return __getSBit(bytes)
```